# Why lumen is not decoding cookies from laravel session correctly.

Tags: laravel, authentication, lumen

I am saving a cookie from Laravel. Cookie name is "log_user" and its value is "582012d94255d0401200002d". When saving from laravel its encrypts the cookie and saves it. 
Now When I read this from lumen it gives me the result

```
 "s:24:\"582012d94255d0401200002d\"
```

in this form. Why this amendment? I am using same APP_KEY in both applications.

Next, when I change the APP_KEY a little, like if I make randomly substitutes some character with some other,  lumen authenticates the user and send it to my Route method.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure exactly why, but the result can be [`unserialized()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to get the result you seek.

Comment: glad to head it 